# How to make a java reflection program output look better?

Tags: java, reflection

I've created a java reflection program similar to javap. Everything works fine but i was wondering if there was a better way to display the output. What i mean by that is I like to take out the java.lang.String whatever in the arguements of each method. Here is my method.
ex. public static void compareTo(String s)

```
public static void displayMethods(String s)
                throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    Class<?> c1 = Class.forName(s);
    Method [] con = c1.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method c: con)
        println(c);
}
```

Here is my output

```
public boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object) 
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString() 
public int java.lang.String.hashCode() 
public int java.lang.String.compareTo(java.lang.Object) 
public int java.lang.String.compareTo(java.lang.String) 
public int java.lang.String.indexOf(java.lang.String,int) 
static int java.lang.String.indexOf(char[],int,int,java.lang.String,int) 
static int java.lang.String.indexOf(char[],int,int,char[],int,int,int)
```

Comment: There are a lot of methods on the `Class<?>` and `Method` that you can use to generate better output. Including the generic aware `Type` implementations. It all depends on how much work you want to put in and what sort of output you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.append(Modifier.toString(method.getModifiers()));
    if (method.getModifiers() != 0) {
        output.append(" ");
    }
    output.append(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName())
          .append(" ")
          .append(method.getName())
          .append("(");
    for (Parameter param : method.getParameters()) {
        output.append(Modifier.toString(param.getModifiers()));
        boolean firstParam = true;
        for (Parameter param : method.getParameters()) {
            if(!firstParam){
                output.append(", ");
            }
            firstParam = false;
            output.append(param.getType().getSimpleName());
        }
        output.append(param.getType().getSimpleName());
    }
    output.append(")");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Example output for `public static final String foo(int x, String y)`:

```
public static final String foo(int, String)
```

The output contains the return type instead of the declaring type, but you can easily change that. For more optimized output that also includes exceptions, you can take a look at the source code of [Method.toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/reflect/Method.java#Method.toString%28%29) and adapt it to your needs.